# JS Snake game operating with two arrays

Tags: javascript

I feel that I almost found solution, but need some help. I have two arrays: one is snakeBody(contains divs that will be body of the snake), second array contains  arrays with coordinats of first element from snakeBody(snakeBody[0]) after he start moving in such form pastCoord = [[20,0], [40, 0], [60, 0]......] (here [coordX, coordY]). Every step is 20px.

I don't know how to apply coords from pastCoord array to elements in snakeBody array.

I think about double for loop, but what to do in this loops I don't know:

```
for (var i = this.snakeBody.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  for (var j = gameObj.pastCoord.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {


  };
```

Here all my code:

```
// field object
var fieldObj = {
  field: document.getElementById( "field" ),
  w: 480,
  h: 580
},
gameObj = {
  pastCoord: [],
  getRandom: function( num ) {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * num );
  },
  createSnakeTarget: function() {
  var snakeTarget = document.createElement( "div" );
      snakeTarget.className = "snake-target";
      snakeTarget.style.top = this.getRandom( fieldObj.h ) + "px";
      snakeTarget.style.left = this.getRandom( fieldObj.w ) + "px";

      fieldObj.field.appendChild( snakeTarget );
  },
  stopGame: function() {
    var stopMessage = document.createElement("div");
        stopMessage.className = "stop-message";
        stopMessage.style.background = "white";

        fieldObj.field.appendChild( stopMessage );
        //TODO: write message to stopGame
  }
};

gameObj.createSnakeTarget();

// snake object
snakeObj = {
  snakeBody: document.getElementsByClassName( "snake-body" ),
  p: {
    x: 0, // position x 
    y: 0  // position y
  },
  v: {
    x: 20, // velocity ( one loop move one unit of snake body)
    y: 20
  },
  keys: {
    up: null,
    l: null,
    r: null,
    down: null
  },
  update: function() {
    if ( this.keys.down ) {
       this.p.x += this.v.x;
    } else if ( this.keys.up ) {
       this.p.x -= this.v.x;
    } else if ( this.keys.r ) {
       this.p.y += this.v.y;
    }else if ( this.keys.l ) {
       this.p.y -= this.v.y;
    }

    for (var i = this.snakeBody.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       this.snakeBody[0].style.top = this.p.x + "px";
       this.snakeBody[0].style.left = this.p.y + "px";
    }

     gameObj.pastCoord.push([this.p.x, this.p.y]);
     console.log( gameObj.pastCoord );
    }
  }
},

//TODO: addEventListener helper function
// after eating snakes become diger and adding to array 
//that you can see the length ag snake

//TODO: find out how to improve correctnes of collision 

// Crome works only with keydown and keyup
window.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
// before changing direction you have to put previous direction to false
  if ( event.keyCode == 38 ) {
      snakeObj.keys.up = true;
      snakeObj.keys.down = false;
  } else if ( event.keyCode == 40 ) {
      snakeObj.keys.down = true;
      snakeObj.keys.up = false;
  } else if ( event.keyCode == 39 ) {
      snakeObj.keys.r = true;
      snakeObj.keys.up = false;
      snakeObj.keys.down = false;
  } else if ( event.keyCode == 37 ) {
      snakeObj.keys.l = true;
      snakeObj.keys.r = false;
      snakeObj.keys.up = false;
      snakeObj.keys.down = false;
  }
}, false);
//TODO: add event hendler to click to some button

 window.addEventListener( "load", function gameLoop() {
   setTimeout( function() {
     snakeObj.update();
     requestAnimationFrame( gameLoop );
   }, 1000);
 });
```

Here is codepen (works only in CHROME) http://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/pamzC 
Thanks for the help

Comment: What do you want your code to do?

Comment: I made a snake a while ago - did it with one array. Each element had the two coordinates of that block. After every move, the new coordinate would be added and the last one would be deleted. If the user 'grew' the snake, the last one would once not be deleted, and so the array would grow. Don't really understand your question - just giving some of my own experience.

Comment: Sorry it's language barier. I want that every loop coordinates from pastCoors array will apply to elements from snakeBody array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a second array if you read the positons of each div in the correct order.

Here is some pseudocode...

```
refreshing the divs:

if the snake is not growing:
   for each div other than the head starting with the end of the tail:
      make the div position the position of the div in front
   move the head according the current direction direction
otherwise:
   add a new div at head end of the snake to be its new head
```

BTW, this is probably not going to work not any better with request animationFrame than using setTimeout on its own.

```
 window.addEventListener( "load", function gameLoop() {
   setTimeout( function() {
     snakeObj.update();
     requestAnimationFrame( gameLoop );
   }, 1000);
 });
```

You have asked to have the function gameLoop called in time to synchronise with with the screen refresh and then said to wait without any synchronisation using setTimeout before actually changing the display.